# How to draw overlapping circles with radial gradient on the edge in a rectangular?

Tags: android, canvas, geometry, rectangles

I wish to draw transparent circles within a black rectangular and the circles overlap partially. I successfully did it by using PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT) to crop off two transparent circles from a black rectangular but now I want to add radial gradient (from transparent to black) on the edge
Can someone tell me how to do so ? Note that this is not just ONE circle. I have at least two circles overlapping

many thanks!

what my code does : https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbr2abgb4esorrj/img1.jpg?dl=0

what I desire : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ihsz77ukbsj1wf/img2.jpg?dl=0

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDimension, mDimension, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAlpha(200);

        paint.setColorFilter(createDimFilter());
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);

        for (Point p : mPoints) {
            Paint transparentPaint = new Paint();
            transparentPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            transparentPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));

            transparentPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawCircle((float) p.x, (float) p.y, radius, transparentPaint);//
            transparentPaint.setXfermode(null);

        }
```